# Postgresql - Getting row with max value in column

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I'd like to form an sql query, which returns some data of rows, which have max value in some group. Consider the following example for a demonstration:

There are three tables: country, publisher and book. Each publisher belongs to one country and each book has one publisher. Definitions could look like

```
Country(country_id, country_name)
Publisher(pub_id, pub_name, fk_pub_country)
Book(book_id, book_name, release_date, fk_book_publisher)
```

I'd like to select (country_id, book_name) grouped by country, so that each row contains the name of the most recently released book in that country. If there are multiple books released on the same day, I should get the one with the highest id.

If I just use group by -clause and max, I cannot include the book name. If I select view (country_id, max_date) and join it with publisher and book, I may receive multiple rows per country. How could I achieve the desired result?

Comment: Homework? Add sample table data and the expected result, both as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt - and describe what's going wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (country_id)
  country_id,
  book_name
FROM country
JOIN publisher ON fk_pub_country = country_id
JOIN book ON fk_book_publisher = pub_id
ORDER BY
  country_id,
  release_date DESC,
  book_id DESC
```

Comment: Thanks! This also seems to be a good solution considering performance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subquery:

```
select c.country_id,
       (select b.book_name 
        from Book b 
             join Publisher p on p.pub_id = b.fk_book_publisher 
        where p.fk_pub_country = c.country_id 
        order by b.release_date desc, b.book_id desc limit 1) as book_name
from Country c
```

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> If I just use group by -clause and max, I cannot include the book
>   name.

But you can't let Postgres boss you around like that. Just grab the first of *n* sorted records from an array of results like so (untested):

```
SELECT
  country_id,
  (array_agg(book_name))[1] as book_name
FROM country
JOIN publisher ON fk_pub_country = country_id
JOIN book ON fk_book_publisher = pub_id
GROUP BY country_id ORDER BY release_date DESC;
```

Since they're ordered how you want, `(array_agg(...))[1]` grabs the first item from the list and, hey, you got a stew goin'.